# Эмуляция входа в Skype

Tags: windows, winapi, skype

Вопрос по использованию Windows API - просто в оконных вещах я полный чайник. В связи с тем, что Скайп заставляет перейти на новую версию, у меня на работе в одном месте возникла проблема - ключ `/password` больше не работает, а мне нужно запускать несколько разных Скайпов *в автоматическом режиме* на одной машине. Раньше хватало запуска с `/secondary/username/password`. Теперь пароль надо вводить руками.

Хочу написать программу, которая бы запускала Скайп, имитировала ввод в его окно входа в сеть имени пользователя и пароля, после чего завершалась бы, а Скайп продолжал работу.

Подскажите, с чего начать, общую схему, так сказать - как такое можно осуществить.

Если есть способ не пользоваться микроскопом для забивания гвоздей, и решить этот вопрос проще - буду только признателен :)

Comment: У скупа SDK нет? Вам обязательно заходить через прогу? Через веб не получится?

Comment: @hedgehogues Машина, на которой пасутся несколько пресловутых "булгактеров". Объяснять, как вводить пароли и т.п. - себе дороже :) Все. Один раз я, наверное, ошибся, настроив таким образом. Пояснить, что больше так не работает - себе дороже... А если я еще и немного на этом научусь работать с внутренностями Windows - так это только лишний бонус :) Так почему бы и нет?

Comment: А если в качестве обходного пути - завести несколько локальных windows учёток и с помощью runas запускать каждую версию скайпа под каждой локальной учёткой?

Comment: @donRumata Тогда надо будет каждой, приходя, заходить в свою учетную запись... ой, нет, только не это :)

Comment: @Harry, autologon? Хотя это не секурно, да.

Comment: Есть такая штукенция http://www.winautomation.com  Наверное, самый простой способ решить конкретную задачу. Доводилось использовать, работает.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Я посмотрю, спасибо. Но теряется такой шанс поразбираться с Windows :)

Comment: @Harry да я понимаю :)